# Android setOnClickListener fired twice by one click

Tags: java, android

I've created an ImageView "reddot" in one of the two fragments of the mainActivity. In the onCreate section of the mainActivity, after finding the ImageView 'reddot' with findViewById(R.id.reddot), setOnClickListener is attahced to 'RedDot'. However, every time I click the reddot, the toast appears twice. Could you please help to see where my code has gone wrong? Thanks!

I have tried to arrange the code in its fragment, the result is the same, click once on 'reddot', the toast text will appear twice. I also checked there is no clickable setting in the XML of the ImageView 'reddot'.

The XML code of 'reddot' for its fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
android:background="@color/white" >


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/reddot"
android:layout_width="21dp"
android:layout_height="21dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
android:src="@drawable/red20px"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The code in onCreate of mainActivity:

```
ImageView reddot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.reddot);

reddot.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String redMsg = "red dot";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        redMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
    );
```

Every time whenever reddot is clicked, the warning messages in Logcat are as following, e.g.  "W/NotificationService: Toast already killed. pkg=com.example.application callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@f4ef1bd" :

```
2019-11-10 00:28:01.190 1631-3134/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 24257815 , only wrote 24257520
2019-11-10 00:28:02.529 1631-3134/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 24321795 , only wrote 24321600
2019-11-10 00:28:03.838 1631-3134/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 24384412 , only wrote 24384240
2019-11-10 00:28:04.409 1631-1730/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 24438504 , only wrote 24411600

    --------- beginning of system
2019-11-10 00:28:04.435 1905-4496/? W/NotificationService: Toast already killed. pkg=com.example.application callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@f4ef1bd
2019-11-10 00:28:04.983 1745-2227/? W/SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: 4f1404e Toast#0
```

Comment: try changing it to an ontouchlistener.

Comment: Thanks, John. I tried "onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)" , and "case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN" to trigger the toast. But it is still the same fault, the text of toast will appear twice.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set onClick() on views of fragment in the main activity.You can use this piece of code in onCreateView() of fragment (The fragment that the reddot is in) :

```
ImageView reddot = (ImageView) getView.findViewById(R.id.reddot);

reddot.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String redMsg = "red dot";
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),redMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
);
```

write this code before returning the view of fragment.

Comment: Thanks, Mahdi. But I tried to re-allocate the code as you suggested, put them in the fragment and before returning the view of the fragment. The problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

toast.show();

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
 toast.cancel(); 
 }
}, 500);
```

Or if this doesn't work you can use an alternative (AppMsg, Crouton or the new SnackBar), or keep a reference to your Toast and cancel() it in your Activity.onPause().

Comment: Thanks, the_underrated. I tried the code and changed the time 500 to 1300, it worked for most of the cases. Thanks for that! I will use this method for now, but still think why and how that issue originates? it would be great if it can be solved from the root cause

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because you are calling `setOnClickListener` in your activity while your view is in the Fragment layout.

```java
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


    ImageView reddot = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.reddot);

    reddot.setOnClickListener(
      new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String redMsg = "red dot";
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    redMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
     );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mahdi-Malv, I have tried as you suggested, the problem remains the same